# How to remove all characters from a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

How can I remove all characters from a string that are not letters using a JavaScript RegEx?

Comment: @RD - What possible answer are you expecting? I don't think it gets much simpler than Paolo's answer... And what "credible and/or official sources"!? That doesn't make any sense...

Comment: a bounty is not a "make tested code for me" button.

Answer (score 58):

You can use the [`replace`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method:

```
'Hey! The #123 sure is fun!'.replace(/[^A-Za-z]+/g, '');
>>> "HeyThesureisfun"
```

If you wanted to keep spaces:

```
'Hey! The #123 sure is fun!'.replace(/[^A-Za-z\s]+/g, '');
>>> "Hey The sure is fun"
```

The regex `/[^a-z\s]/gi` is basically saying to match anything not the letter a-z or a space (\s), while doing this globally (the `g` flag) and ignoring the case of the string (the `i` flag).

Comment: Just checked it in the console and it worked great. I wonder if he wanted to keep spaces.

Comment: +1 But I'd use the slightly more efficient equivalent: `replace(/[^A-Za-z\s]+/g, '');` This will match more than one char in each "gulp", and the case-sensive mode can be slightly faster with some regex engines.

Comment: Note that this will also remove accentuated characters, which in my opinion are letters.

Comment: One issue is going to be duplicate spaces (with the keep spaces method) - just chain it with another replace: `replace(/[^A-Za-z\s]+/g, "").replace(/\s+/, " ");`

Comment: @Caseman You mean `….replace(/[^A-Za-z\s]+/g, "").replace(/\s+/g, " ")`. Also note that strings are immutable, so `"foo".replace(…);` as-is makes little sense.

Answer (score 12):

[RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) instance properties used `g` , `i`

> global : Whether to test the regular expression against all possible matches in a string, or only against the first.
>
> ignoreCase :
>       Whether to ignore case while attempting a match in a string.

[RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) special characters used `[a-z]` , `+`

> [^xyz] : A negated or complemented character set. That is, it matches anything that is not enclosed in the brackets. You can specify a range of characters by using a hyphen.
>
> For example, `[abcd]` is the same as `[a-d]`. They match the 'b' in
>   "brisket" and the 'c' in "chop".
>
> + : Matches the preceding item 1 or more times. Equivalent to {1,}.

JavaScript [string replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) method syntax

> str.replace(regexp|substr, newSubStr|function[, Non-standard flags]);

The non-standard flags `g` & `i` can be passed in the replace syntax or built into the regex.
examples:

```
var re = /[^a-z]+/gi;   var str = "this is a string";   var newstr = str.replace(re, "");   print(newstr);

var str = "this is a string";   var newstr = str.replace(/[^a-z]+/, "", "gi");   print(newstr);
```

To match whitespace characters as well \s would be added to the regex `[^a-z\s]+`.

[JavaScript Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference)

Comment: Flags are in the ECMAScript standard. But the third (flags) argument of `String.prototype.replace` is [JavaScript-proprietary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). Avoid in favor of flags on first (RegExp) argument.

Answer (score 8):

Regular Expressions in [ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) implementations are IMHO best explained at the [Mozilla Developer Network (formerly, Mozilla Developer Center)](https://developer.mozilla.org/) in the [`RegExp` article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) of the [JavaScript Language Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/) pp.

However, as noted, the previous answers do not take *non-English* letters into account, such as umlauts and accented letters.  In order not to remove those letters from the string, you have to exclude them from the character range like so:

```
var s = "Victor 1 jagt 2 zwölf 3 Boxkämpfer 4 quer 5 über 6 den 7 Sylter 8 Deich";

s = s.replace(/[^a-zäöüß]+/gi, "");
```

This approach quickly becomes tedious and hard to maintain, especially if *several* natural languages need to be considered (and even in proper English there are foreign words like "*déjà vu*" and "*fiancé*").

Therefore, among other [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) features, [JSX:regexp.js](http://pointedears.de/websvn/filedetails.php?repname=JSX&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fregexp.js)  lets you use Regular Expressions that can use Unicode property classes, through the [Unicode Character Database (UCD)](http://unicode.org/ucd/).

You would then write¹

```
var s = "Victor 1 jagt 2 zwölf 3 Boxkämpfer 4 quer 5 über 6 den 7 Sylter 8 Deich";

var rxNotLetter = new jsx.regexp.RegExp("\\P{Ll}+", "gi");

s = s.replace(rxNotLetter, "");
```

or

```
var s = "El 1 veloz 2 murciélago 3 hindú 4 comía 5 feliz 6 cardillo 7 y 8 kiwi. La cigüeña tocaba el saxofón detrás del palenque de paja"
      + " – Съешь 1 же 2 ещё 3 этих 4 мягких 5 французских 6 булок, да 7 выпей 8 чаю.";

var rxNotLetterOrWhitespace = new jsx.regexp.RegExp("[^\\p{Ll}\\p{Lu}\\s]+", "g");

s = s.replace(rxNotLetterOrWhitespace, "");
```

to reduce dependency on the uppercase/lowercase quirks of implementations (and be more extensible), for a `RegExp` that excludes all non-letter Unicode characters (and white-space in the second example).

[Testcase](http://PointedEars.de/scripts/test/regexp)

Be sure to provide a version of the Unicode Character Database as well, because it is large, in flux, and therefore not built into regexp.js (JSX contains a verbose text and compacted script version of the UCD; both can be used, and the latter is preferred, by regexp.js). Note that [a conforming ECMAScript implementation does not need to support characters beyond the Basic Multilingual Plane (U+0000 to U+FFFF)](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-2), so `jsx.regexp.RegExp` currently cannot support those even though they are in the UCD.  See the documentation in the source code for details.

¹ [Pangrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangram) from [Wikipedia](http://wikipedia.org/), the free encyclopedia.