# Replace URL or fully qualified domain name with link

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not good at regular exp. 
and I want to change the link to hyperlinks in a text

for example

```
Hello http://stackoverflow.com
Hello www.stackoverflow.com
```

I want the stackoverflow to link

```
Hello <a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>http://stackoverflow.com</a>
Hello <a href='http://www.stackoverflow.com'>www.stackoverflow.com</a>
```

I used this

```
var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file|):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
        return str.replace(exp,"<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>");
```

But this is only with http://

Thank in advance

Comment: It is hard to figure out what a link is without the protocol.People sometimes write like this.Is this a link? :)

Comment: You're going to struggle to match "stackoverflow.com" without risking turning text into links that people didn't intend to be.

Comment: OK what should I do to make it like the above any hints ?

Comment: To prevent false positives don't auto-link anything that doesn't have the protocol. Do what they do here and use angled brackets to force linking, like <stackoverflow.com>.

Comment: @user457104 can you please write down the new regular expression ?

Comment: @KillerX I think we can accept as an axiom here that you cannot solve social problems with technology. If people mistype, there will be problems. I do not know any natural language where the full stop may be followed by anything other than whitespace. Therefore, that a "link" must not contain whitespace is a good first indication that is a "link".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have said, first you need to define what is a "link". (Note that "link" is only short for "hyperlink" in this context, so that sentence of yours does not make sense.) Taking your two examples into account, you want to match [*Uniform Resource Identifiers (URIs)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier) and [*Fully Qualified Domain Names* (FQDNs)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) instead.

To do that, you should take the regular expression that can be found in [RFC 3986, Appendix B](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-B) –

```
^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
```

– and change it into one that matches at word boundaries, accepts only FQDNs and optional port numbers after the `//`, and stops at whitespace (`\s`):

```
      ,----scheme----.   ,-Fully Qualified Domain Name-.,-port.,--path--.,---query----.,fragment
      |              |   |                             ||     ||        ||            ||       |
(^|\s)(([^:/?#\s]+):)?(//([A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Za-z0-9-]+(:\d+)?([^?#\s]*)(\?([^#\s]*))?(#(\S*))?
```

Then you can make the scheme part optional –

```
                          |
                          v
(^|\s)((([^:/?#\s]+):)?//)?(([A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Za-z0-9-]+(:\d+)?([^?#\s]*)(\?([^#\s]*))?(#(\S*))?
```

– and write this as a regular expression literal (slashes in the expression need to be escaped as they serve as delimiters):

```
/(^|\s)((([^:\/?#\s]+):)?\/\/)?(([A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Za-z0-9-]+)(:\d+)?([^?#\s]*)(\?([^#\s]*))?(#(\S*))?/
```

(You might want to match [IDNs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) too; JSX:regexp.js and its support for Unicode character properties can help you there, see [How to remove all characters from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015844/beginner-javascript-regex-how-to-remove-all-characters-from-a-string/8568325#8568325).  And you might want to prepend to the FQDN subexpression a subexpression for the optional and deprecated transmission of user names in the URI, `(\w+@)?`, for proxy access.)

Then you can replace *all* strings (`g`lobal modifier) that this would match with a corresponding `a` element:

```
var rx = /(^|\s)(((([^:\/?#\s]+):)?\/\/)?(([A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Za-z0-9-]+)(:\d+)?([^?#\s]*)(\?([^#\s]*))?(#(\S*))?)/g;

str = str.replace(rx,
  function (match, optionalWhitespace, uri, scheme, p4, protocol, fqdn, p7, port,
            path, query, queryVal, fragment, fragId) {
    return (optionalWhitespace ? optionalWhitespace : '')
      + '<a href="' + (protocol ? uri : 'http://' + uri)
      + '" target="_blank">' + uri + '<\/a>';
  });
```

You must assume here that when you see only a FQDN prefix, it is the domain name of a not secured web site, and prepend `http://`.  Otherwise the URI-reference in the `href` attribute would refer to a potentially existing path in *your* website, that has the domain name as its name (`http://your-site.example/other-site.example.com`), which is probably not what you want.

It is possible, but not likely, that this expression matches too much in your case; test with as much input as available, and adapt as needed.  If backwards compatibility is not an issue, use [non-capturing parentheses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) (`(?:…)`) for efficiency and less named parameters; see the [ECMAScript Support Matrix](http://PointedEars.de/es-matrix) for details.

Capturing the FQDN part – the parentheses around `([A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Za-z0-9-]+` – is optional; you may want to use it to give the `a` element a `class` attribute value to format it in a special way, like prepending a fitting icon, for example for a link to Stack Overflow, Wikipedia, Twitter, or Facebook.

You may also want to reconsider using the `target` attribute ([for Strict (X)HTML, you MUST remove it](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-A)). Users probably do not take kindly on not having control about where a link target is opening. Provide hints in the form of titles, icons, cursors, etc. instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
var exp = /(((?:(?:https?|ftp|file):)?\/\/)?(?:[\w-]+\.)?[\w-]+\.\w{2,5}(?:\/[^\s\/]*)*)/ig;
return str.replace(exp, function(_, link, protocol){
    return link.link(protocol ? link : "http://" + link);
});
```

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Your problem was that the protocol could be ignored. Edited the code above.

Comment: The expression is too greedy; it will match any text. And in which "old browsers" have you observed `$&` to not be available?

Comment: I've heard that some old IEs don't support it. I'm working on the expression.

Comment: Okay, now it works. And the regular expression became extremely ugly.

Comment: Thank you very much i will start learning regex soon so I will work on it 
but now it works good for me

Comment: @FB55 It is far from being universal, though. For a start, think about IDNs and new TLDs.

Comment: As for "old IEs": JScript 5.0 in IE 5.0 is one implementation that does not support non-capturing parentheses (`(?:…)`). And `String.prototype.link()` is proprietary. It will _not_ add the `target` attribute (provided you want that).