# JavaScript - Why does my parseInt return NaN?

Tags: javascript, parseint

```
var bucketId = $.cookie('bucketId');
console.log(bucketId);

var bucketIdNumber = parseInt(bucketId, 10);
console.log("bucketIdNumber " + bucketIdNumber);
```

In the code about bucketId returns "17".
So why when I parseInt bucketId do I get NaN?

Comment: Are you sure that `bucketId` is `"17"`?

Comment: `parseInt` does return `NaN` if it couldn't parse a string to a number. E.g. `parseInt('asdf10')` would return `NaN`

Comment: because bucketId is not really 17 :D this is why it works when you hardcode `var bucketId = '17';`

Comment: yeah, according to console.log()

Comment: @Mark: Post the *exact* string that gets printed out via `console.log()` (or `JSON.stringify()`).

Comment: If `console.log(bucketId==="17")` logs `true` I guess this isn't the actual code you are using

Comment: post the output of `window.btoa(bucketId);` this will base64 encode it, giving us a binary safe representation of your string so we can inspect it. but, you could also do stuff like check the string length yourself and you'll see your problems.

Comment: you can always debug it, why waste bandwidth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, the code above is equivalent to:

```
var bucketId = '"17"';
console.log(bucketId);

var bucketIdNumber = parseInt(bucketId, 10);
console.log("bucketIdNumber " + bucketIdNumber);
```

In which case, bucketIdNumber does return NaN.  You will need to further parse this cookie, and remove any inner quotation marks.

Comment: Oh yeah, the quotes are actually what's logged, not for formatting

Comment: That sounds like it might be it? What's the best way to remove the inner quotation marks?

Comment: Not storing them in the first place is the best way. The other way is to remove them everytime with `parseInt( bucketId.replace(/^"|"$/g, ""), 10)`

Comment: @Mark, as @Esailija mentioned, if you could avoid storing them, that would be ideal.  If not, then you could use RegExp to remove them.  Something like what is done here: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015844/how-to-remove-all-characters-from-a-string`

Comment: Esailija - that was it, I parseInt() before I put it in the cookie now.

Answer (score 1):

`bucketId` probably doesn't start with an integer.

> If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseInt() returns NaN.

Comment: It could be a Chrome-only thing, but ```parseInt('    12    ', 10)``` works for me.